# Permutation Invariant Tree Gradient Boost Models

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

Suppose we are dealing with a classification problem whose input is a bag of users $u_i$ and their data, stored as $u_{ij}$ . Each user might have $n$ features like age, gender, description, purchase habits, etc, which we would store as $u_{ij}$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,n$.

I'm curious if there are tree GBM models similar to XGBoost and CatBoost, which would be invariant under permuting these users groups. To be concrete, naively we would train a GBM using row vectors of $[u_{11},\cdots,u_{1n}, u_{21}\cdots, u_{2n},...]$. I'd like the model to be invariant under permutations of the blocks of $[u_{i1},\cdots,u_{in}]$. I could accomplish this with neural networks by using an attention layer.

Comment: Apologies, I cannot understand the question. Is the unit of analysis the "bag of users" or a single user? Are all bags equi-sized? If a single user $u_i$ has $n$ features $[u_{i1}, \dots, u_{in}]$ then that is the "row vector"? What is described as "row vectors" is a bit unclear as it seems to concatenate row vectors together to form another row vector... On the other hand permutations of $[u_{i1}, \dots, u_{in}]$ seem to refer to the order of the features? (Off the top of my head, I would say that maybe DART boosters seems *somewhat* relevant...)

Comment: Yes the analysis is over a fixed set of users, say K input users. Each user has $n$ features that can be represented as a vector. The model takes in features from all $K$ users and I want it to be invariant under permutation of any pair of users. That’s why I’m speaking of permuting blocks of features.